# issue while zooming content of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, zooming

i am developing an application in which i am placing a set of images on a scrollView.i could place the images and given the contentSize as required to fit all the number of images.each imageView is of size 768,1024.i set the property  of pagingEnabled to YES on the scrollview,to move to next image as the user swipes. i am loading each image into the imageview on scrolling the scrollView. **i.e** - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

**issue:**
the issue i face is when i zoom a UIImageView the imageView is getting zoomed but the zoomed imageView is being overlapped by its next imageView with its size assigned i.e 768,1024. i included the delegate methods as below.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
return [scrollView viewWithTag:tempTag-1];
```

}

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view{
scrollView.pagingEnabled=NO;
[scrollView viewWithTag:tempTag].frame=CGRectMake(scrollView.contentSize.width-768, [scrollView viewWithTag:tempTag].frame.origin.y, [scrollView viewWithTag:tempTag].frame.size.width, [scrollView viewWithTag:tempTag].frame.size.height);
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale{
if (scrollView.zoomScale<=1) {
    scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
}
}
```

i tried to change the frame of the next imageView to current ImageView depending on the content size but it didn't work.

can some one help me in this regard..

TNX in advance

Comment: Did you get anything on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a scrollView of sub-scrollviews to hold the imageViews. Then configure zoom on each sub-scrollviews.